# using -webkit-transform: scale() to zoom image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a navigation bar and an image below it.
I'm using -webkit-transform: scale() to zoom image on hover, but when it is scaled up it hides my navigation bar. I want it to zoom below my navigation bar. ( not behind it so zindex doesn't apply.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#on{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
#img1:hover{ -webkit-transform:scale(2,2);}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    width = 100px;
    height:70px;
    }
</style>
<nav>
<div id = "toolbar">
<input type="image" src="Icons/i.svg" width="50" height="50" id="I" class = "s">
<input type="image" src="Icons/e.svg" width="50" height="50" id="E"class = "s">
<input type="image" src="Icons/index.svg" width="50" height="50" id="index"class = "s">
</div>
</nav>


<div id ="on"><img src="Icons/bright.png"  alt="" width="100" height="100" id="img1"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps you can help by providing some code that you have tried

Comment: It sounds like you could achieve this by some other method rather than using `transform`s, but we can't know unless we have some sample code to go off of.

Comment: I've added the code. I want to use transform only so that I can use css transition property to animate.

Comment: @ShreyAnand You can do that with `background-size`, see my demo.

Answer (score 1):

Use a background image.

```
.zoom:hover {
    background-size: 200%;
}
```

**Animated example**

```css
.zoom {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.zoom:hover {
    background-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom"></div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj5a14m2/)**

Comment: 1) I am planning to put my image on canvas so can't use background image. 2) I want the size of the whole image container to increase and then postiiton itself below my navigation bar. In your demo the size of the container of image remains constant and image magnifies.

Comment: No but I mentioned webkit transform scaling so it is obvious that I want the whole image to increase in size, also I want to magnify an 'image' like I said in my question and not a 'background image' so the question is specific. Thanks for your help anyway :)